# tkinter - Modify image position on main window

Tags: tkinter, plot, position

I'm going to build a small GUI where to show some images and Plot on the main window. On the GUI i placed on the left side some buttons to do somethings. One of them is to show an image.
When i click on this button, the image is placed on the center of the main window but i would like to choose where to place it.
To set the position of the image i'm using the command pack() but i can't define the position. If i use grid(row, column...) i obtain the following error:

cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack

This is part of the code, for the plot. The "img" i want to show is a matrix that i need to display as image.

```
def plot():
    fig = Figure(figsize=(6,6))
    a = fig.add_subplot(111)
    a.imshow(img)
    a.invert_yaxis()

   a.set_title ("Acquired data", fontsize=16)
   a.set_ylabel("Frame", fontsize=14)
   a.set_xlabel("Pixels", fontsize=14)

   canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=mainwindow)
   # canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
   canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=200, row=100, rowspan=5, sticky="nesw")
```

There are some specific commands to use with pack() in order to set the position of the image?

Answer (score 0):

I found that instead to use .pack() i can use the command .place() on canvas.

```
canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x=250,y=20)
```